# 16 queens puzzle

Tags: combinatorics, chess

Can you place 8 white queens and 8 black queens on an 8x8 grid, such that no two queens of the same colour occupy the same row, column or diagonal?

Comment: See your comment on your post https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/94766/knights-attacking-exactly-three-knights

Comment: yeah I feel that this one is somewhat different.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is

> Yes.

> Take any one of the [well-known 8-queen solutions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eight_queens_puzzle) together with its horizontal or vertical mirror image.

Comment: The next question is how many independent sets can you place?  Can you place 8 sets?

Comment: @FlorianF good question. I don't think 8 sets is possible, but more than 2 should be possible. Worth asking.

Comment: See [this question](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/44085/20814) for the 8 sets version.

Comment: I suspect that as long as a 90-degree rotation doesn't end up with two queens of opposite colors on the same square, you can use 90-degree rotations as well. Also 180-degree rotations (as opposed to reflections).

Answer (score 9):

For the question of maximizing the number of sets of $8$ queens, define a graph with a node for each of the $92$ solutions for $8$ queens and an edge for each pair of solutions that share a cell.  Now find a maximum independent set in this graph.  The maximum turns out to be

> $6$, achieved as follows:
> \begin{matrix}&6&5&4&.&3&2&.&1\\&.&1&3&2&4&5&6&.\\&5&4&.&6&1&.&2&3\\&2&.&1&3&.&6&5&4\\&1&.&2&5&.&4&3&6\\&3&6&.&4&2&.&1&5\\&.&2&5&1&6&3&4&.\\&4&3&6&.&5&1&.&2\\\end{matrix}